# Why is my returned string displaying null in other methods?

Tags: java, serialization

I have successfully serialized objects and when the files are saved, they are given a filename which is the teamname chosen. This works fine. However when I try to de-serialize the files, I get a `FileNotFound` exception, and it's looking for a file called null.ser which doesn't exist.

However my String "fileName" displays the correct name of the file i.e. Arsenal.ser , when I have just saved it. Indeed I can see a file called Arsenal.ser and it contains sufficient bytes to suggest the file was serialized successfully.

Below are some code snippets, I have scoured the web to find a solution. I presume it's the way I am using the `return` statement? Please don't suggest wholesale changes, I am learning! I just want to understand why it's pointing at null, rather than my saved file(s).

```
public class WriteClub{
    public String tryWriteClub(ClubInfo club){

        String fileName = "/home/cg/root/" + club.teamName + ".ser";

        try{
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(club);

            System.out.println("Serialized data is saved in" + fileName);
            System.out.println("Filename is" + fileName);
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Serializer extends WriteClub
{
    public void Serialize()
    {
        MainMenu pass_choice = new MainMenu();
        int passed_choice = pass_choice.chooseTeam();

        if(passed_choice==1){
            ClubInfo club = new ClubInfo("Arsenal" , "Emirates" , "Premier League" , 11122333 , 60000);
            tryWriteClub(club);
        } // end if 1
```

---

```
public class DeSerializer
{
    public void DeSerialize(String fileName)
    {
        String fN = fileName;
        ClubInfo club;
        System.out.println("File name is:" + fN);
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("/home/cg/root/" + fileName + ".ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            club = (ClubInfo) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println("Club class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Saved game loaded...");
        System.out.println("Name: " + club.teamName);
        System.out.println("Stadium: " + club.stadium);
        System.out.println("Division: " + club.division);
        // System.out.println("SSN: " + club.SSN);
        System.out.println("Stadium Capacity: " + club.stadiumCapacity);
    }
}
```

---

To call my DeSerialize method

```
case 3:
DeSerializer load = new DeSerializer();
load.DeSerialize(fileName);
exit = true;
break;
```

Comment: Check what's passed in the fileName parameter to `DeSerialize(String fileName)`, probably it's null.

Comment: I have already done that, see the assignment to "fN" in the deSerialize method. . It does pass "null" to fileName, I don't know how to fix that or understand why that's happening. "fileName" points to the clubname in my  tryWriteClub method. I just want it to point to the serialized filename and then deserialize it.

Comment: filename doesn't point to the filename in WriteClub.  WriteClub dutifully returns the filename as a string, but Serialize ignores it, so the name gets lost.  So if you called load.DeSerialize("/home/cg/root/whatever_the_club_name_is.ser"); does it work?

Comment: That doesn't work, you can't have a slash because the IDE will immediately put in double quote marks. Can anyone explain why Serialize() is ignoring my returned value ?

Comment: Have you found the solution? If not, please post the exception and add some more code from Serializer class

Comment: There is no other relevant code for the Serializer class. I just have more if statements to serialize more objects based on the team chosen. The program compiles and runs but, I cannot de-serialize an object, because it is looking for "null.ser", when it should be looking for fileName.ser , I am successfully writing to the hard disk (the saved file has a large number of bytes) and the programs name the file as Arsenal.ser or whichever team name,

Comment: Is anyone able to answer this question? Thanks in advance :)